# Setup.exe installing prerequisites even if they are preinstalled

Tags: .net, deployment, installation, windows-installer, bootstrapper

I am deploying a .NET application with .NET Framework 4.0 and VS 2010 C++ redistributable as prerequisites.

When the setup.exe runs in a machine with the prerequisites satisfied the bootstrapper install them again.

Is this a known issue? and what's the correct way to solve it?

Comment: Does it actually reinstall them? In the runtime case at least it needs to updating an install reference count so that the runtime doesn't get uninstalled with someone else's application - I'm not sure how .NET handles this as I expect it'd survive the uninstall.

Comment: I've had issues where it wants to install the .NET 4 CL when i need the .NET 4 and it keeps installing the Cl over and over (until i visit microsoft.com/net/ and get the full package). But that's the extent of my issues.

Comment: What conditions are being used for the redistributables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Libraries prerequisite keeps popping up on a VS 2010 created installer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785328/visual-c-2010-runtime-libraries-prerequisite-keeps-popping-up-on-a-vs-2010-cre)

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to edit the bootstrapper product.xml file to contain the correct product code for the Visual Studio C++ Redistributable.

See the post below which contains the steps to fix this:

[Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Libraries prerequisite keeps popping up on a VS 2010 created installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785328/visual-c-2010-runtime-libraries-prerequisite-keeps-popping-up-on-a-vs-2010-cre)