# Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Libraries prerequisite keeps popping up on a VS 2010 created installer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, setup-project, bootstrapper

I created an installer with Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40.219.1 SP1 Rel. My application is built/compiled for x86 and requires VC++ runtime libraries. Thus, the setup project is configured with VC++ runtime libraries as a prerequisite.

Every time I run the installer I get the popup "The following components will be installed on your machine." "Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Libraries (x86)". The first time it gets installed asa expected. The second and subsequent times it asks me whether to repair or remove VC++ 2010.

This popup should only be displayed once, the first time it is discovered that VC++ redistributable is not installed.

Has anyone seen this? Anyone know how I can fix this?

**Solution:**

The answer I accepted gave me what I needed to resolve the issue. Here are the details on what I did to fix this, which was very simple in fact. I edited the file:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\vcredist_x86\product.xml
```

In this file you will find the following:

```
<InstallChecks>
    <MsiProductCheck Property="VCRedistInstalled" Product="{6EE91C1A-A2E7-38CD-AEBB-3B900A4D8868}"/>
</InstallChecks>
```

The above contains the incorrect product code. Replace the above with the correct product code for the Visual C++ 2010 SP1 redistributable as follows:

```
<InstallChecks>
    <MsiProductCheck Property="VCRedistInstalled" Product="{F0C3E5D1-1ADE-321E-8167-68EF0DE699A5}"/>
</InstallChecks>
```

The link [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/05/10008146.aspx) shows the correct product codes for the various VC++ 2010 Redistributables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setup.exe installing prerequisites even if they are preinstalled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797057/setup-exe-installing-prerequisites-even-if-they-are-preinstalled)

Comment: True, it was a duplicate, but it was not answered. This post, now has the answer and steps required to fix the issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This happens because the prerequisite detection criteria is incorrect.

A solution is to create your own custom prerequisite with a correct criteria. Perhaps this article will help:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/05/10008146.aspx

Visual Studio setup projects do not support this. But it can be done by manually generating the required manifests.

You can find the manifests structure here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229223(VS.80).aspx

These manifests can be generated automatically with the [Bootstrapper Manifest Generator](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg) tool.

After generating the package manifests, you can add all these files (including the package) in a separate folder in the Visual Studio prerequisites folder, for example:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\
```

You can then select the prerequisite in your setup project properties page.

Comment: I copied the vcredist_x86 folder into vcredist_x86_fixed and renamed a string in the .xml file of the "en" folder that I thought was the text shown in the Prerequisites dialog, but there are no additional entries in that dialog. I have restarted VS. Must I do something in addition to get the new package to show up in the prerequisites dialog?

Comment: Make sure that your new prerequisite uses a custom name. Or at least delete the original prerequisite folder. Prerequisites with duplicate names are not supported.