# VS2010 Setup Project with C++ 2008 Redistributables?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-project

Here is the situation:

- I have a Visual Studio **2010** Setup project which installs a C# executable
- The installation includes a C# dll that references a C++ dll
- The C++ dll requires the C++ **2008** libraries

The problem is that it is very easy to make the setup project install the C++ 2010 libraries, but I am not having much luck trying to install 2008.

- For 2010, it is as simple as selecting C++ 2010 in the Properties > Prerequisites section of the project. 2008 is not an option.
- I have found much documentation about using merge modules to install C++ redistributables. However, in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules directory of my machine, I only have C++ 2010 merge modules. I have not been able to find the C++ 2008 merge modules available for download from any reputable source.
- I can download the [redistributable installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336) easily enough, but I do not know how to make the setup project use it.
- I found this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on creating bootstrapper packages. Hopwever, the [Bootstrapper Manifest Generator](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg) only seems to work for VS2008 and VS2005 (see comments).

I do not have the authority/ability to do any of the following, which I believe could resolve the issue:

- Install VS2008 to get the correct merge modules
- Use a different installer program, like InstallShield.
- Re-compile the C++ dll to use the 2010 libraries.

If anyone has encountered and resolved this issue before, I welcome your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add C++ 2008 redistributables as prerequisites in VS 2010, I found the following steps to be effective:

1. Determine the product key for the redistributable. There is a good list here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2009/01/29/9384143.aspx
2. Add the installation executable and corresponding xml files to the bootstrapper directory (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages`), as explained here: http://insomniacgeek.com/clickonce-4-0-package-for-the-c-2008-sp1-redist-atl-security-update/
3. Restart VS, and check the prerequisites list for the setup project. All should now be present.

Also, as an aside, I discovered that unless you take the steps outlined in this question: [Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Libraries prerequisite keeps popping up on a VS 2010 created installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785328/visual-c-2010-runtime-libraries-prerequisite-keeps-popping-up-on-a-vs-2010-cre) your C++ 2010 redistributables will always try to install, even if they are already present.

Answer (score 1):

The merge modules come along with VS2008 and a VS2008 license. Whoever created the C++ dll which depends on the 2008 runtimes probably has a license for VS2008. You can ask them to provide it to you - it's legal to do so.

Comment: Ok, suppose I don't have access to that person. Suppose the dll in question is something that was made a long time ago, and now I need to incorporate it into a new application. I know this is not a great situation, but it's what I'm given.